# error when installing polymer on directory windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, git, bower, polymer

I am getting an error when I try to install polymer in a directory on windows 7. I have installed NodeJS and bower. When I go into the directory via command prompt and run the Polymer install command it throws this error: "GIT is not installed or not in the Path. "bower ENOGIT git is not installed". I have GIT installed and added the directory as a repository.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

my first thought about this is, that you don't have git as %PATH% variable.

Everything bower does as far as i understand is that it tries to get the needed things from github which means bower clones the project for you in the bower_components directory.. with no further search to the given error ("bower ENOGIT git is not installed") i'd say that git is missing in your %PATH% variables as i already mentioned. You can easily test this out by opening a cmd and type "git" in it. The expected result should be something like:

```
$ git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
   add        Add file contents to the index
   bisect     Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
   branch     List, create, or delete branches
   checkout   Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree
   clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
   commit     Record changes to the repository
   diff       Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
   fetch      Download objects and refs from another repository
   grep       Print lines matching a pattern
   init       Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one
   log        Show commit logs
   merge      Join two or more development histories together
   mv         Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink
   pull       Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch

   push       Update remote refs along with associated objects
   rebase     Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
   reset      Reset current HEAD to the specified state
   rm         Remove files from the working tree and from the index
   show       Show various types of objects
   status     Show the working tree status
   tag        Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG

'git help -a' and 'git help -g' lists available subcommands and some
concept guides. See 'git help <command>' or 'git help <concept>'
to read about a specific subcommand or concept.
```

I hope that this answer helps you at least a little

Comment: I got it to work by adding git in the path variable in the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the path to the environment variables fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It actually only hides the deeper problem. which is that nodejs on windows will only resolve paths for spawn using the windows %PATH% environment variable.

This means that if you are using bash on windows through something like Cmder, then despite having `/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/` or `c:\\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\Git\\bin` in your $PATH, nodejs will not find your git binary, because it's not looking there and you'r not running a shell that exposes %PATH%.

fun times. yay windows is great!